Constructor precedence with templatized constructor
I'm looking to create a wrapper pointer SpecialPtr and it is following rule of 5, but also has a templatized constructor below. When using the wrapper pointer in a vector, the vector class wants to use the templatized constructor instead, causing a compilation error like this
<source>:22:9: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo(SpecialPtr<Foo>&)'
   22 |         new T(std::forward<F>(first), std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:14: note: candidate: 'Foo::Foo(int)'
    7 |     explicit Foo(int x): val(x) {}
      |              ^~~
<source>:7:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SpecialPtr<Foo>' to 'int'
    7 |     explicit Foo(int x): val(x) {}

Full link https://godbolt.org/z/nMjExMT1a
This is confusing to me because I'd expect the non templatized constructors to take precedence over it. The code below works because of adding a requires, why is it necessary?
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(int x): val(x) {}
    int val;
};

template<typename T>
struct SpecialPtr {
    SpecialPtr() noexcept = default;
    SpecialPtr(const SpecialPtr&) = default;
    SpecialPtr(SpecialPtr&&) = default;
    ~SpecialPtr() = default;
    SpecialPtr& operator=(const SpecialPtr&) = default;
    SpecialPtr& operator=(SpecialPtr&&) = default;
    
    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    // Why is this requires necessary?
    requires(!std::derived_from<std::decay_t<F>, SpecialPtr>)
    explicit SpecialPtr(F&& first, Args&&... args) {
        new T(std::forward<F>(first), std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
    }
    T* ptr;
};



int main () {
    vector<SpecialPtr<Foo>> v;
    vector<SpecialPtr<Foo>> v_2;
    v_2 = v; // Entrypoint for the error

    return 0;
}


See explanation the template version is chosen over the non-template move ctor as the templated version has a non-const parameter and p1 is also nonconst. in the dupe.

The code can be simplified
    SpecialPtr<Foo> v;
    SpecialPtr<Foo> v_2(v);

When the compiler copy-constructs v_2 from v, it tries to match a constructor to the argument type SpecialPtr<Foo>&. The constructor template is the best match, because it does not need any argument conversion, F&& first is deduced to SpecialPtr<Foo>& first. Hence the compiler chooses the exactly matched template, and its body fails to use its arguments.
The copy constructor SpecialPtr(const SpecialPtr&) does not match better, because it needs the argument conversion SpecialPtr<Foo>& → const SpecialPtr<Foo>&.
You can add the overloaded copy constructor
    SpecialPtr(SpecialPtr&) = default;

It will match the argument exactly and the non-template constructor will be chosen prior the template.
https://godbolt.org/z/zTWTWex6c

Forwarding constructors win against the copy constructor in overload resolution when a non-const lvalue reference is passed.
In v_2 = v, std::vector will internally call the constructor of SpecialPtr as if by
// given SpecialPtr<Foo> other
SpecialPtr<Foo> p(other);

Because other is not const, the forwarding constructor wins in overload resolution; it doesn't require adding a const whereas this would be needed for the copy constructor.
F deduces to SpecialPtr<Foo>& and Args deduces to the empty pack.
This is a known and common issue; see Beware of Perfect Forwarding Constructors by Michael Park for more details.
The requires clause you have commented out is a common solution to the problem: by constraining F so that SpecialPtr cannot be passed to the forwarding constructor as the first parameter, you can make the copy or move constructor win in overload resolution.
The C++ standard library runs into this issue a lot.
For example, the constructor std::span(R&&) (7) only participates in overload resolution if std::remove_cvref_t<R> is not a specialization of std::span.
As you can see, the conventional solution is to constrain the forwarding constructor, though there are other solutions, such as declaring all four constructors (T(T&), T(const T&), T(T&&), T(const T&&)).
See also Perfect forwarding constructor and deleted constructors
